# S3 connectors to connect with Kafka for streaming data from on-premise to cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, connector

I want to stream data from on-premise to Cloud(S3) using Kafka. For which I need to intsall kafka on source machine and also on cloud. But I don't want to intsall it on cloud. I need some S3 connector through which I can connect with kafka and stream data from on-premise to cloud.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in Avro or Json format (or can be converted to those formates), you can use the S3 connector for Kafka Connect. See [Confluent's docs on that](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/s3_connector.html)

Should you want to move actual (bigger) files via Kafka, be aware that Kafka is designed for small messages and not for file transfers.

Comment: I want for log files, which are not in Avro or Jason. Apart from Confluent can you please suggest some other connector.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: You can try your luck with the ones listed at https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Comment: @NamanAgarwal You can send raw lines of log files directly to Kafka. Then using JSON or Avro Converter in kafka-connect-s3 will output `{"line": "message"}` records by default on S3. In other words, the destination can be in a different format than the source. Plus, for log analytics, Avro would be more compressed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [kafka-connect-s3](https://github.com/spredfast/kafka-connect-s3/) project consisting of both sink and source connector from Spreadfast, which can handle text format. Unfortunately it is not really updated, but works nevertheless